# How to count number of digits after a decimal place?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am new to writing queries. I need a query that tells the number of digits after a decimal place.

Eg:

```
1001.00 = 0 digits after decimal
1001.01 = 2 digits after decimal
1001.010 = 2 digits after decimal
```

How can I do this?

Comment: (1) Please tag your question appropriately.  MySQL and Oracle are two different databases.  (2) With a floating point representation, there is no correct answer to your question.   1001.00 is the same as 1001.9999999999....

Comment: Question doesn't make sense assuming values are stored as floats.

Answer (score 6):

***ORACLE SOLUTION***

> This can be achieved by multiple ways one of them is below,

```
SELECT
length((1001.00) - trunc(1001.00)) - 1 as digits_after_decimal
FROM
dual;
SELECT
length((1001.01) - trunc(1001.01)) - 1 as digits_after_decimal
FROM
dual;    
 SELECT
length((1001.010) - trunc(1001.010)) - 1 as digits_after_decimal
FROM
dual;
```

Comment: I believe the poster is looking for 3 different values in the scenario given. If that is what this yields, can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah, my second query will give the same output as required in the given scenario.

Answer (score 2):

for oracle simple example:

```
select length(substr(to_char(999999.564654645),instr(to_char(999999.564654645), ',')+1, 16)) || ' digits after decimal' from dual
```

Comment: I believe the `substring_length` parameter (3rd parameter of `substr`) can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

This solution which worked for me in MySQL, and should work for any numeric field:

```
SELECT char_length(field + 0) - char_length(floor(field + 0)) - 1 as digits_after_decimal;
```

Essentially, I am looking to count the characters of the entire representation of the numeric string, then removing the decimal to get the character length of everything *not* in the decimal, and comparing the difference.

For example, if you have `1039.320293` as your input:

```
SELECT char_length(1039.320293); #returns 11
SELECT floor(1039.320293); #returns 1039
SELECT char_length(floor(1039.320293)) #returns 4
```

And the initial solution would return 6 (since you have to remove the character for the decimal place as well).

The "plus zero" will remove trailing zeros from the number before doing the floor, which should address the cases you have added.

Comment: It would be nice if you also add a little explanation what your query is doing. I see you are using the `char_length` function to find the length of string representation of decimal value, then you subtract the string length of floored value. Minus one is for adjusting for the decimal point character "." in string representation